# How to check AJAX requests in Firebug even after page redirects?

Tags: ajax, firebug

I have the requirement to register/login at `www.somesite.com` from my site page. So I am using cURL POST to do that.

**Problem:**

`www.somesite.com` is using AJAX to submit the registration form and after the registration it's redirecting quickly. So I am unable to catch the request in Firebug or the Firefox DevTools. I also don't have server-side access to `www.somesite.com`.

Is there any way to catch network requests on redirection, so I can check the request parameters?

Comment: use chrome developer tools, there is an option called "preserve logs" so logs are not cleared even if page refreshes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firebug there is a *Persist* button within the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel), which allows you to keep the previous requests:

[image: Persist button within Firebug's Net panel]

In the Chrome DevTools you can achieve this by checking the *Preserve log* option within the *Network* panel:

[image: Preserve log checkbox within Chrome DevTools' Network panel]

The Firefox built-in DevTools offer an *Enable persistent logs* option within their options panel:

[image: Enable persistent logs checkbox within Firefox DevTools' Options panel]